# Pylance for VScode doesn't show tooltip suggestions anymore

Tags: tooltip, pylance

I previously had Pylance tooltip suggestions that showed me the available options I could enter, but for some reason it stopped working:

[No tooltip suggestions with Pylance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czwv5.png)

I've uninstalled vscode, deleted AppData\Roaming\Code and %userprofile%.vscode, reinstalled vscode, reinstalled python and pylance, but the suggestions still don't show as they did previously.

When I disable Pylance, tooltip suggestions work as expected:
[Tooltip suggestions without Pylance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Fh0.png)

There's nothing exotic in the settings.json (profile) file (which is the selected profile - the settings.json for user and workspace are both empty).
[settings.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTlI4.png)

Can you help me identify what's causing this? I've spent the whole day trying to enable/disable various pylance settings to get this to work again, but I'm stuck.